# Related to C# WPF MVVM, how can I bind a TexBox.Text in an “View” with changing content from a string in a “model” file?

Tags: c#, mvvm, binding, textbox

I am doing my first steps with C#, WPF, MVVM. I’m trying to implement a simple serial terminal. I'm actually almost done. I can click buttons in my MainView and also evaluate values in the comboBox to select the correct interface. The whole thing has worked very well so far in the MVVM model. But in the last step I have problems getting received serial data from the “model” via the “viewmodel” to the “view”. For me is not clear how I have to implement it. I’m using “CommunityToolkit.Mvvm” for my implementation.

My files are:

- Model/SerialInterface.cs
- ViewModel/MainViewModel.cs
- View/MainWindow.xaml

The beginning from the model file looks like this:

```
namespace SimpleUART_1.Model
{
    public class SerialInterface : ObservableObject
    {
        SerialPort uart = new SerialPort();
        private string[] possibleComPorts;
        private string CurrentComPort;
        private string dataIN;
        public string terminalContent;
```

...

Further the methods:

```
private void uartDataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
  dataIN = uart.ReadLine();
  Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)FillTerminalContent);
}

private void FillTerminalContent()
{
  terminalContent += dataIN.ToString();
  terminalContent += "\n";
}
```

The beginning from the viewmodel file looks like this:

```
namespace SimpleUART_1.ViewModel
{
    public class MainViewModel : ObservableObject
    {
        // the viewmodel have to know the model.
        private Model.SerialInterface serial;


        public string TerminalText
        {
            get { return serial.terminalContent; }
            set => SetProperty(ref serial.terminalContent, value);
        }
```

And finally the view file has, among other things, this content:

```
<Canvas Name="UARTTerminal" IsEnabled="True">
        <!--Headline-->
        <GroupBox x:Name="grbComPortControl" Height="109" Header="Com Port Control" Width="151" Canvas.Left="26" Canvas.Top="124" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
        <!--Headline-->
        <Label x:Name="lblHedline" Width="300" Height="50" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"
                     FontSize="20" FontWeight="Bold" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center"
                     Canvas.Left="250" Canvas.Top="0"  Content="Simple IR-Box terminal"  />
        <Label x:Name="lblComPort" Content="COM PORT" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="30,148,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
        <Label x:Name="label" Content="{Binding StatusText}" Height="20" Canvas.Left="104" Canvas.Top="207" Width="65" Background="{Binding StatusColor}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="9"/>
        <ComboBox x:Name="cobComPort" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="65" Height="22" Canvas.Left="104" Canvas.Top="152" ItemsSource="{Binding GetAvailableComInterfaces}" />
        <Button x:Name="btnReset" Content="Renew" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="104,179,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="65" Height="20" RenderTransformOrigin="-0.432,0.403" Command="{Binding RenewComPorts}" />
        <Button x:Name="btnConnect" Content="Connect" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="32,179,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="65" Command="{Binding ConnectComPorts}" CommandParameter="{Binding SelectionBoxItem, ElementName=cobComPort}" />
        <Button x:Name="btnDisconnect" Content="Disconnect" Width="65" Canvas.Left="32" Canvas.Top="207" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top" Command="{Binding DisconnectComPorts}" />
        <GroupBox x:Name="grbReceiverTerminal" Height="180" Header="Receive Terminal" Width="271" Canvas.Left="239" Canvas.Top="80">
            <TextBox x:Name="txbTerminal" HorizontalAlignment="Left" TextWrapping="Wrap" Width="257" Text="{Binding TerminalText}"/>
        </GroupBox>
    </Canvas>
```

As I wrote, all things except the textbox “txbTerminal” working fine. The textbox does not updated when I receive something via serial interface. When I set a breakpoint to the method “FillTerminalContent” then the string “terminalContent” does have the correct content.
I just started with C# WPF a few weeks ago so I’m still a beginner.

I’m not sure if it is correct from my side to implement the serial interface in the model or in the viewmodel?

BTW: I have no problem to post all my code but I'm not sure if it will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

From what you've posted, you're binding against `MainViewModel.TerminalTest`, assuming that you've set `MainViewModel` as you View data context, and yet you're not setting it.
Instead you appear to be setting `SerialInterface.terminalContent` as evidenced by

```
private void FillTerminalContent()
{
  terminalContent += dataIN.ToString();
  terminalContent += "\n";
}
```

You need to set `MainViewModel.TerminalTest` in order to trigger the notification event.

I would suggest that you place an event handler or delegate within `MainViewModel` that sets `TerminalText` that is triggered when data arrives from from the serial port.

Answer (score 0):

I picked up a book and now I was able to solve the problem myself. But I'm posting here again code snippets so that others don't make the same mistake.

In the “model” file I declare, instantiate and at the end trigger the event:

```
namespace SimpleUART_2.Model
{
  public class SerialInterface : ObservableObject
  {
    // first step:  => declaration of the event (delegate keyword)
    public delegate void DelegateUartReceive(string content);
    // second step: => instantiation of the event (event keyword)
    public event DelegateUartReceive EventUartReceive;
    // ....

private void uartDataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
  UartContent = uart.ReadLine();
  // Step three:    => Triggering the event
  EventUartReceive?.Invoke(UartContent);
}
```

In the “viewmodel” file I created these strings:

```
private string terminalText;
public string TerminalText
{
  get { return terminalText; }
  set { SetProperty(ref terminalText, value); }
}
```

And further instantiate and register the event in the constructor:

```
public MainViewModel()
{
  // ...
  // instantiate object
  serial = new Model.SerialInterface();
  // register event handler
  serial.EventUartReceive += new Model.SerialInterface.DelegateUartReceive(EventHandlerUartReceive);
}
```

At least I created the event handler:

```
// event handler
public void EventHandlerUartReceive(string text)
{
  if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(text))
  {
    TerminalText = String.Empty;
    return;
  }
  TerminalText += text;
}
```

The “view” file does have this in its “xaml” file:

```
<TextBox x:Name="txbTerminal" HorizontalAlignment="Left" TextWrapping="Wrap" Width="257" Text="{Binding TerminalText}"/>
```

Now everything is working as expected.